# Entity Framework Update Foreign Key constraint may cause multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a project that is using entity framework and I'm getting the following error when I try and update my database.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.VisualManualWebPageFiles_dbo.VisualManualHeaders_VisualManualHeaderID' on table 'VisualManualWebPageFiles' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint.

Here are the classes that are being used for this.

First With a VisualManualHeader class.

```
<Table("VisualManualHeaders")>
Public Class VisualManualHeader
    <Key>
    Public Property VisualManualHeaderID As Integer

    <Required>
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property VisualManualPages As ICollection(Of VisualManualPage)
    Public Overridable Property VisualManualWebPageFiles As ICollection(Of VisualManualWebPageFile)
End Class
```

Then a VisualManualHeader has the associated VisualManualPages with it like the following.

```
<Table("VisualManualPages")>
Public Class VisualManualPage
    Enum VisualManualPageType
        VIDEO
        IMAGE
        TEXT
        WEBPAGE
    End Enum

    <Key>
    Public Property VisualManualPageID As Integer

    <Required>
    Public Property Title As String

    Public Property VisualManualHeaderID As Integer
    <ForeignKey("VisualManualHeaderID")>
    Public Overridable Property VisualManualHeader As VisualManualHeader

    Public Property Content As String

    Public Property PageType As VisualManualPageType

    Public Overridable Property VisualManualWebPageFiles As ICollection(Of VisualManualWebPageFile)
End Class
```

The pages can then have many VisualManualWebPageFiles associated to the page.

```
<Table("VisualManualWebPageFiles")>
Public Class VisualManualWebPageFile
    <Key>
    Public Property VisualManualWebPageFileID As Integer

    <Required>
    Public Property VisualManualHeaderID As Integer
    <ForeignKey("VisualManualHeaderID")>
    Public Overridable Property VisualManualHeader As VisualManualHeader

    <Required>
    Public Property VisualManualPageID As Integer
    <ForeignKey("VisualManualPageID")>
    Public Overridable Property VisualManualPage As VisualManualPage

    Public Property FileLocation As String
End Class
```

I have a feeling the problem is in the VisualManualWebPageFiles class due to the foreign key of the VisualManualHeader as if I remove this I can then update my project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies with the association of the entity classes. Taking a look at your code seems that `VisualManualHeader` and `VisualManualPage` are in Many-To-Many relation; i.e. one instance of `VisualManualHeader` can be associated with many instances of `VisualManualPage`, and the the reverse is also true.

If that is indeed the case then, the relation between 2 classes are represented in `VisualManualWebPageFile` correctly and there is no need of keeping unnecessary properties in both `VisualManualHeader`, and `VisualManualPage`. I have tried to remove the same as follows:

`VisualManualHeader`

```
<Table("VisualManualHeaders")>
Public Class VisualManualHeader
    <Key>
    Public Property VisualManualHeaderID As Integer

    <Required>
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property VisualManualWebPageFiles As ICollection(Of VisualManualWebPageFile)
End Class
```

`VisualManualPage`

```
<Table("VisualManualPages")>
Public Class VisualManualPage
    Enum VisualManualPageType
        VIDEO
        IMAGE
        TEXT
        WEBPAGE
    End Enum

    <Key>
    Public Property VisualManualPageID As Integer

    <Required>
    Public Property Title As String

    Public Property Content As String

    Public Property PageType As VisualManualPageType

    Public Overridable Property VisualManualWebPageFiles As ICollection(Of VisualManualWebPageFile)
End Class
```

`VisualManualWebPageFile`

```
<Table("VisualManualWebPageFiles")>
Public Class VisualManualWebPageFile
    <Key>
    Public Property VisualManualWebPageFileID As Integer

    <Required>
    Public Property VisualManualHeaderID As Integer
    <ForeignKey("VisualManualHeaderID")>
    Public Overridable Property VisualManualHeader As VisualManualHeader

    <Required>
    Public Property VisualManualPageID As Integer
    <ForeignKey("VisualManualPageID")>
    Public Overridable Property VisualManualPage As VisualManualPage

    Public Property FileLocation As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically correct. The WebPageFiles does not need a reference to the ManualHeader table - and it actually could cause errors.

Example:

ManualPage ID 10 is owned by ManualHeader 1. You add WebPageFiles ID 15 with ManualPage 1 - but there is nothing stopping you setting WebPageFiles.ManualHeaderID to 3 as long as ManualHeader 3 exists. You now have a WebPageFile which a bit confused about who its grandparent is.

The correct way is to set the parent ID only (ManualPage). This parent will contain the ID of its own parent (ManualHeader) and so the child (WebPageFile) can unambiguously fing its grandparent via its parent.